# Get Browser Width Regadless of Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website that has a full screen layout. When I zoom out I would like to keep the layout the same and shrink all the content.

I need the max-width of my page container to be whatever the browser width is (without zoom factored in)

I thought this would have been easy with this:

```
function zoomify(){

    var htmlDocWidth = $( window ).width();

    $('.page-wrap').css( 'max-width',htmlDocWidth );

};

$(window).resize(function(){
    zoomify();
});

zoomify();
```

but $( window ).width() seems to change based on zoom. Is there a way to get the width of the users browser window without zoom factored in?

Comment: Try `var htmlDocWidth = '100vw';`

Comment: @zer00ne shouldn't it be `vw`?

Comment: @void Indeed my bad, corrected.

Comment: Here, zoom factor doesn't impact any issues. It's applays for both get&set so there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: 100vw is still 100% width when zoomed out. It would seem the viewport "grows" when the page is zoomed out.

Comment: I found this. http://htmldoodads.appspot.com/dimensions.html. This fellow is able to keep the window.outerWidth dispite the zoom. This is what I need I can't figure out how he's done it

Comment: Looks like the constant you're looking for is `window.outerWidth` according to that page (bookmarked, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('.page-wrap').css( 'max-width','100vw' );
```

Here `vw` is a unit which means the `width` of `viewport`, for height you can use `vh`.

Comment: This doesn't give the intended result. The viewport is "growing" when zoomed out so 100vw is equivalent to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
function zoomify(){

    var htmlDocWidth = window.outerWidth;

    $('.page-wrap').css( 'max-width',htmlDocWidth );

};

$(window).resize(function(){
    zoomify();
});

zoomify();
```

Comment: window.outerWidth was it. It got me the browser width and didn't care about the zoom like innerwidth does. I am able to show things based on the screen size now. Thanks